# Convertendo horas totais de um mês em dias e horas

Tags: lista, data, if, for, append

Olá!

Estou trabalhando em um data_set em que a medida de tempo está em Horas Totais Corridas do mês. Indo desde a hora 1 até a hora 734.
Quero converter essa medida de tempo em horas do mês por dia.

**Por exemplo:**

- Input:

step = [1, 2, 3, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]

- Outputs:

hour = [1, 2, 3, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2]

```
for s in step:
i = 1
upper_range_hour = i*24 
lower_range_hour = upper_range_hour-24 
if (s >= lower_range_hour) & (s < (upper_range_hour)): 
    if s < 24: 
        hour.append(s)
    else:
        hour.append(s%lower_range_hour)
else:
    hour.append(0)
    i += 1
```

Porém o retorno que tenho é o seguinte para este exemplo:
[1, 2, 3, 22, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Alguém pode me ajudar? Creio que o problema está talvez na soma do "contado i" OU no "hour.append(s%lower_range_hour)"

Obrigado!

Comment: "em que a medida de tempo está em horas do mês" e depois "quero converter essa medida de tempo em horas do mês". Acho que está meio controverso. Pode editar a pergunta? :)

Answer (score -3):

Olá! Provavelmente existe uma solução mais simples mas deixo a minha para você pensar ou solucionar o seu problema temporariamente:

```
$hora = 0;
$dia = 1;
$horas = 734; // horas pre definidas
// cria um array associativo onde cada hora é um novo array que possui valores como hora e dia
for($i = 0; $i < $horas; $i++)
{

    if($hora != 24){
        $arr[$i] = $time=['hora' => $hora,'dia' => $dia];
    } else {
        $hora = 0;
        $dia++;
        $arr[$i] = $time=['hora' => $hora,'dia' => $dia];
    }
    $hora++;
}
// seu input
$step = [1, 2, 3, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50];

// para cada input ele separa por associação em um novo array
foreach($step as $item){
        $newarr[] = $arr[$item];
    }
    
// array_column separa a coluna hora e dias do array em um novo array
$horas_finais = array_column($newarr,'hora');
$dias_finais = array_column($newarr,'dia'); 

//print...
echo "horas: ";
print_r($horas_finais);
echo "<br>";
echo "dias: ";
print_r($dias_finais);

//saidas
// horas: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 22 [4] => 23 [5] => 0 [6] => 1 [7] => 2 [8] => 3 [9] => 22 [10] => 23 [11] => 0 [12] => 1 [13] => 2 )
// dias: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 2 [6] => 2 [7] => 2 [8] => 2 [9] => 2 [10] => 2 [11] => 3 [12] => 3 [13] => 3 )
```

**Obs:** Fiz em PHP que é minha linguagem, mas creio que facilmente consiga adaptar para a linguagem que está acostumado.